# Might copying bit order of unsigned char array into single precision floating point player (IEEE 754) cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c

Q1. Assuming there is no trap representation, sizeof(float)=4, CHAR_BIT=8, architecture is little endian and compiler behaves float within IEEE 754 standart, would the code which is placed below cause an undefined behaviour?

Q2. May I use safely(if I am guaranteed that the conditions above are met) same approach in networking to convert little-endian (int) into big-endian (int) where sizeof(int)=4.

```
if(sizeof(float) == 4 && CHAR_BIT == 8 && is_little_endian()){
    unsigned char c[4];
    /* 11111111 10000000 00000000 00000000 */
    c[0]=0x0;
    c[1]=0x0;
    c[2]=(1UL<<7);
    c[3]=UCHAR_MAX;

    /*print_bits(c[3]);
    print_bits(c[2]);
    print_bits(c[1]);
    print_bits(c[0]);
    printf("\n");*/

    float f = 0.0f;
    memcpy(&f, c, sizeof(float));
    printf("float: %f\n", f);
}
```

(The question is asked for educational purposes to understand some concepts in depth.)

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the real problem you need to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Educational purposes to understand some of the C concepts in depth.

Comment: As long as you are absolutely confident that the value representation is accurate, there is in principle nothing different between doing this and transferring a value in some other way such as file access.